# SQL convert Rows to columns without pivot

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen several posts on this many of which suggest Pivot. That might be a good solution but my SSMS is 2016 which dose not support Pivot. I am trying to mimic a MS Access report that used VBA to format the columns. I have been working on this for a year and I am still no closer to solving it, here is the Problem.
My data is stored in a table in rows that are grouped by PC_Pack_Id. I added the ColNum field to indicate what column the data goes in. Didn't know if that would help. I included a script to create a Input table.
The output needs to have 9 columns (See example). Column 1 will always be the PC_Pack_Id. RET_ENV always goes in Column 8, RET_ENV always goes in COLUMN 9. Missing Columns Should have a header of "INSERT". The headers should be the same for all the INPUT rows but will not always be the same every time it runs. I am thinking read the table once to get the header row data. Once you have a header row then a while loop to update the Columns. I am just guessing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Input Record Layout--
PC_Pkg_Id   Char(3)  The Group field
ColNum      Int      The column across they need to appear in
PC_CompType Char(20) Column Header
PC_CompName Char(20) Column value

output Layout--
[image]

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[CompTable]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompTable] (    [PC_Pkg_Id] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,  [ColNum] [int] NOT NULL,    [PC_CompType] [varchar](20) NULL,   [PC_CompName] [varchar](20) NULL, ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CompTable]
           (
            [PC_Pkg_Id]
           ,[ColNum]
           ,[PC_CompType]
           ,[PC_CompName]
           )
     VALUES  ('GNL','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNL','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNL','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNL','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNL','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNL','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNM','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNM','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNM','3','BROCHURE','FK140(50) R11/21') ,('GNM','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNM','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNM','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNP','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNP','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNP','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNP','4','BROCHURE','FK213(28) R7/22') ,('GNP','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNP','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNQ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNQ','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNQ','3','BROCHURE','FK213(09) R7/22') ,('GNQ','4','BROCHURE','FK140(09) R11/21') ,('GNQ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNQ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNR','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNR','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNR','3','BROCHURE','FK140(15) R11/21') ,('GNR','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNR','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNR','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNS','1','PAPER','FN319') ,('GNS','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GNS','3','LETTER','FM839-19 R11/21') ,('GNS','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNS','5','BROCHURE','FK213(19) R7/22') ,('GNS','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNS','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNX','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNX','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNX','3','BROCHURE','FK213(05) R7/22') ,('GNX','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNX','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNX','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNY','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNY','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNY','3','BROCHURE','FK140(25) R11/21') ,('GNY','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNY','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNY','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNZ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNZ','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNZ','3','BROCHURE','FK140(36) R11/21') ,('GNZ','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNZ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNZ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOA','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOA','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOA','3','BROCHURE','FK140(45) R7/22') ,('GOA','4','BROCHURE','FK213(45) R7/22') ,('GOA','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOA','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOB','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOB','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOB','3','BROCHURE','FK140(49) R11/21') ,('GOB','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GOB','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOB','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOC','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOC','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOC','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOC','4','BROCHURE','FK213(42) R11/21') ,('GOC','5','INSERT','FN843(42) R11/21') ,('GOC','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOC','8','OUT_ENV','E6536-TX') ,('GOE','1','PAPER','FN319') ,('GOE','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOE','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOE','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GOE','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOE','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOF','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOF','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOF','3','LETTER','FN782-11 R11/21') ,('GOF','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOF','5','BROCHURE','FK213(11) R7/22') ,('GOF','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOF','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOO','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOO','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOO','3','LETTER','FO586-24 R11/21') ,('GOO','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOO','5','BROCHURE','FK213(24) R7/22') ,('GOO','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOO','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOQ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOQ','2','LETTER','FR639-33') ,('GOQ','3','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOQ','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOQ','5','BROCHURE','FK213(33) R7/22') ,('GOQ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOQ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOS','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOS','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOS','3','BROCHURE','FS397(48)') ,('GOS','4','BROCHURE','FS398(48)') ,('GOS','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOS','8','OUT_ENV','E6058')

GO
```

Comment: SSMS is the client tool and not what does or doesn't support PIVOT.  SQL Server is the product.  What does `SELECT @@Version;` return?  THAT is what version you have.  SQL Server 2016 definitely supports PIVOT.

Comment: If your SQL Server version supports DROP TABLE IF EXISTS then it supports PIVOT.

Comment: Martin could you provide a example as I tried and get a error. the database is 2019

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: It didn't like AggregateFunction

Comment: That doesn't mean that PIVOT is not supported.  What's the full error?  Post your attempt at the PIVOT and then we can help with that.

Comment: Even if it *didn't* support `PIVOT` (which I think was introduced in SQL Server 2005, but maybe earlier..?) you could use conditional aggregation. But if you are using a version of SQL Server *prior* to 2005, you have a much bigger problem; you are using a version of SQL Server that has had *no* support for well over **6 years**, and a version that SSMS 16 doesn't even support either.

Comment: It didn't like AggregateFunction But as I go through the example again I don't know if I am supposed to be using AggregateFunction. I assumed that would be like PC_Pkg_Id. Guess i used the wrong example

Comment: As mentioned, show us your actual attempt and tell us the error, @WIlliamBurke .

Comment: I'm really not at all clear on what you are trying to do. Can you post an example of the expected output? And is this a typo?: "RET_ENV always goes in Column 8, RET_ENV always goes in COLUMN 9." Both columns have the same name? Similarly, you are trying to get multiple columns with the name "INSERT"?

I think I might see what you're trying to do now. Based on "ColNum", you want that to designate where certain values from another column populate?

Comment: Larmu I agree, my company is converting our older Servers to 2019. But we have a lot of legacy systems so its taking awhile.

Comment: No its not a typeo, See output Layout (example)  on the original question. Yes I see what you re saying Should be RET_ENV always goes in Column 8, OUT_ENV always goes in COLUMN 9. I changed the question to reflect this.

Comment: Sql is best for data manipulation (ie dml) and poor at presentation which is why a presentation layer is such as ssrs is useful. Having said that this can be done by building a  conditional aggregation sql query and presenting it to dynamic sql. Before I start coding though can you expand on what you mean by missing columns should be headed INSERT - do you mean the colnum and PC_CompName is present but PC_CompType is not?

Answer (score 0):

I went with a different approach, and this needs logic tweaking (I'm assuming you'd know enough about the specific use cases to do this) but this gets pretty close. You'll need to add exception logic to the `CASE`'s but I think this can do what you want with a little extra tweaking.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CompTable

CREATE TABLE #CompTable (    [PC_Pkg_Id] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,  [ColNum] [int] NOT NULL,    [PC_CompType] [varchar](20) NULL,   [PC_CompName] [varchar](20) NULL, ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #CompTable
           (
            [PC_Pkg_Id]
           ,[ColNum]
           ,[PC_CompType]
           ,[PC_CompName]
           )
     VALUES  ('GNL','1','PAPER','FK212') 
     ,('GNL','2','LETTER','FK172') 
     ,('GNL','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') 
     ,('GNL','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') 
     ,('GNL','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') 
     ,('GNL','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') 
     ,('GNM','1','PAPER','FK212') 
     ,('GNM','2','LETTER','FK172') 
     ,('GNM','3','BROCHURE','FK140(50) R11/21') 
     ,('GNM','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') 
     ,('GNM','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') 
     ,('GNM','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') 
     ,('GNP','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNP','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNP','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNP','4','BROCHURE','FK213(28) R7/22') ,('GNP','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNP','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNQ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNQ','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNQ','3','BROCHURE','FK213(09) R7/22') ,('GNQ','4','BROCHURE','FK140(09) R11/21') ,('GNQ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNQ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNR','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNR','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNR','3','BROCHURE','FK140(15) R11/21') ,('GNR','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNR','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNR','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNS','1','PAPER','FN319') ,('GNS','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GNS','3','LETTER','FM839-19 R11/21') ,('GNS','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNS','5','BROCHURE','FK213(19) R7/22') ,('GNS','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNS','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNX','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNX','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNX','3','BROCHURE','FK213(05) R7/22') ,('GNX','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GNX','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNX','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNY','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNY','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNY','3','BROCHURE','FK140(25) R11/21') ,('GNY','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNY','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNY','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GNZ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GNZ','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GNZ','3','BROCHURE','FK140(36) R11/21') ,('GNZ','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GNZ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GNZ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOA','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOA','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOA','3','BROCHURE','FK140(45) R7/22') ,('GOA','4','BROCHURE','FK213(45) R7/22') ,('GOA','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOA','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOB','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOB','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOB','3','BROCHURE','FK140(49) R11/21') ,('GOB','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GOB','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOB','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOC','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOC','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOC','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOC','4','BROCHURE','FK213(42) R11/21') ,('GOC','5','INSERT','FN843(42) R11/21') ,('GOC','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOC','8','OUT_ENV','E6536-TX') ,('GOE','1','PAPER','FN319') ,('GOE','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOE','3','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOE','4','BROCHURE','FK213 R11/21') ,('GOE','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOE','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOF','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOF','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOF','3','LETTER','FN782-11 R11/21') ,('GOF','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOF','5','BROCHURE','FK213(11) R7/22') ,('GOF','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOF','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOO','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOO','2','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOO','3','LETTER','FO586-24 R11/21') ,('GOO','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOO','5','BROCHURE','FK213(24) R7/22') ,('GOO','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOO','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOQ','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOQ','2','LETTER','FR639-33') ,('GOQ','3','LETTER','FM906') ,('GOQ','4','BROCHURE','FK140 R11/21') ,('GOQ','5','BROCHURE','FK213(33) R7/22') ,('GOQ','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOQ','8','OUT_ENV','E6058') ,('GOS','1','PAPER','FK212') ,('GOS','2','LETTER','FK172') ,('GOS','3','BROCHURE','FS397(48)') ,('GOS','4','BROCHURE','FS398(48)') ,('GOS','7','RET_ENV','E2243 R2018') ,('GOS','8','OUT_ENV','E6058')

GO

SELECT PC_Pkg_Id
    , PAPER=MAX(PAPER)
    , LETTER=MAX(LETTER)
    , BROCHURE=MAX(BROCHURE)
    , BROCHURE=MAX(BROCHURE1)
    , [INSERT]=MAX([INSERT])
    , [INSERT]=MAX(INSERT1)
    , RET_ENV=MAX(RET_ENV)
    , OUT_ENV=MAX(OUT_ENV)
FROM (
    select PC_Pkg_Id
        , [PAPER] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 1) = 1  then PC_CompName end 
        , [LETTER]= case when ISNULL(ColNum, 2) = 2  then PC_CompName end 
        , [BROCHURE] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 3) = 3 then PC_CompName end 
        , [BROCHURE1] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 4) = 4  then PC_CompName end 
        , [INSERT] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 5) = 5  then PC_CompName end 
        , [INSERT1] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 6) = 6  then PC_CompName end 
        , [RET_ENV] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 7) = 7 then PC_CompName end 
        , [OUT_ENV] = case when ISNULL(ColNum, 8) = 8 then PC_CompName end 
    from #CompTable
    ) A
GROUP BY PC_Pkg_Id
```

Comment: Thank you, JW. I'll play with this but hard coding the column heading will make this not work for the next set of packages that may have no brochures and 4 inserts. PC_CompType needs end up in the header

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this will work for this question. Can anyone help me with how I would use PIVOT for this. Just curious to see how that would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could generate sql code and execute it eg

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 
stuff(
(select concat(' max(case when t.colnum = ', s.colnum ,' then PC_CompName end) as ' ,pc_comptype ,',')
from 
(select distinct colnum,case when pc_comptype is null then '[Insert]' else pc_comptype end pc_comptype from t) s
for xml path(''))
,1,1,'')

set @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql) -1)
set @sql = (select concat('select PC_Pkg_Id, ', @sql ,' from t group by PC_Pkg_Id'))

--select @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```